# KeyError trying to plot a filtered dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I cannot figure this one out for the last two hours.  I keep getting a `KeyError` when trying to plot a filtered dataframe. Here is the code of the dataframe I wish to plot ( I'm looking to have `x-axis= 'LengthService'` and the `y-axis= 'AbsentHours'`):

```
df2_ls = df2['LengthService'] >= 4.0
df2['AbsentHours'] >= 100
df2[df2_ls].head()

df2_ls = pd.DataFrame(df2_ls)
```

@RafaelC Here are `df2's columns`:
    Index(['EmployeeNumber', 'Gender', 'LengthService', 'AbsentHours'],   dtype='object')

I feel like I need to `re-index` columns or define certain columns as `keys` maybe?

Here is the `KeyError` message lines :

```
    -> 3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
    KeyError: 'AbsentHours'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    KeyError                   Traceback (most recent       call last)
    <ipython-input-89-2c9592ccb984> in <module>()
    1 # Male bar plot
    2 
    ----> 3 Male = df3_ls.plot.bar(x='LengthService', y='AbsentHours',      rot=0)
    4
```

Comment: which lines yields an error? seems ike your column has different names than the ones your input.. maybe you have whitespaces around them? Print `df2.columns` and check